# changing fonts in matplotlib not working properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

i have a problem changing the fonts in mathplotlib. I try to build an 3d-plot and want the axis to be in arial font. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


# Argumentwerte als 1D Arrays erzeugen
x_Leistung = np.linspace(1050,1350,100)
y_Vorschub = np.linspace(0.8,1.2,200)

# Argumentwerte als 2D Arrays erzeugen
x_Leistung, y_Vorschub = np.meshgrid(x_Leistung, y_Vorschub)

# Interessante Daten erzeugen
z_Nahtbreite_Kupfer = 497.142+114.478*((x_Leistung-1200)/150)+16.313*(0/15)-39.4*((y_Vorschub-1)/0.2)+(0/15)*(((y_Vorschub-1)/0.2)*13.432)+(0/15)*((0/15)*(-53.144))

# Plotten
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x_Leistung, y_Vorschub, z_Nahtbreite_Kupfer, cmap=plt.get_cmap("gist_gray"))

#Achsen labeln
rcfont = {'fontname' : 'Arial'}
ax.set_xlabel('$power (W)$', size='medium',**rcfont)
ax.set_ylabel('$welding speed (m/min)$', size='medium',**rcfont)
ax.set_zlabel('$weld seam width copper  (mm)$', size='medium',**rcfont)


plt.show()
```

there is no error, but the font is still the default one. any ideas to change this? When i try helvetica there is an error for not finding the font, but no error for Arial...

thx for the help

Comment: Your text is enclosed by `$` signs. This means that matplotlib's mathtext is responsible for rendering them. However for mathtext there are only a few fonts available. Best remove the dollar signs, then you should see Arial font.

Comment: thx, that helped a lot! the axis labels are now in arial, bot not the numbers for the scala. is there a command i forgot?

Comment: Do you want *everything*  in Arial? In that case remove all individual font settings and put `plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Arial"` on top of your script.

Comment: thx so much. thats everything i needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell this error is raised because the font is not installed.

On windows, check the 'charmap'. All of those fonts can be used.

Helvetica is not included by default it would seem. You'll have to find it and install it. Tried and tested my end using Windows 10 and python 3.7

Comment: seems to be the case for helvetica, but for arial there is no error. still the default font, not arial

Comment: That is because arial is an installed font. You won't get an error because it can find it. Helvetica cannot be found, it needs to be installed.

Comment: wait... are you saying that even if you specify arial the font is still the standard Matplotlib font?